# Athena Query "mismatched input 'partition'" when trying to add partition

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

Here is my Athena Query. I am trying to add a partition to a table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE public_data_scraping_yahoo_finance_pricing_table
ADD PARTITION ("S3_DATE" = '2021-07') 
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/enriched_data/pricing/2021-07/';
```

I'm following the [documentation as seen here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-add-partition.html) But I'm getting some sort of syntax error.

When I run it I get:

```
line 2:5: mismatched input 'partition'. expecting: '.', 'add' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: 8dd2f1ac-d197-4c4c-b2fc-024383fd30fb; proxy: null)
```

I have run other queries to add partitions before, and have never had this issue. I would expect this query to create the partition without any issues.

Is someone able to help me identify the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so it turns out the issue was because the partition field I was specifying was wrapped in double quotes `"S3_DATE"` when it **shouldn't** be.

So the correct query would be:

```sql
ALTER TABLE public_data_scraping_yahoo_finance_pricing_table
ADD PARTITION (S3_DATE='2021-07') 
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/enriched_data/pricing/2021-07/';
```

Comment: Well, I figured having dashes probably didn't help. But I don't know if that actually solved the issue, since I've kept this new table name. I think using the double quotes as Athena suggests would allow me to keep dashes in the table name.

Answer (score 8):

Can you try to remove the quotes from the table name? This fixed this error for me when trying to remove partitions

Comment: That results in `line 1:19: mismatched input '-'. expecting: 'schema', 'table'` so I think the quotes need to be there because of the dashes in the table name.

Comment: Oh my bad, didn't see that. For escaping special characters in DDL you should use backticks (`) according to the Athena documentation, can you try that?

Comment: So like this `public\`-data\`-scraping_yahoo\`-finance_pricing_table` ?

I'm not sure if this is right, but it also produces an error. `line 1:19: mismatched input '\`-data\`'. expecting: 'schema', 'table' `

Comment: No, the whole table name into backticks!

Comment: Ahhh hehe! My bad.... That results in

`line 1:13: backquoted identifiers are not supported; use double quotes to quote identifiers` so seems like it has to be double quotes.

Comment: So it seems like that Athena really does not support the dash in the table name. Since the table is Glue (Hive) and Athena is Presto, there are some uncompatibilities :/

Comment: Thanks for your help Robert. I will try changing the table name and see if that helps.

Comment: If it does, I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately it hasn't fixed the problem :(

Comment: This helped me when trying to drop partitions. I had "databasename"."tablename" and when I removed the quotes, it worked. I find this odd because the syntax that Athena deploys when I select "preview table" is in the format "databasename"."tablename". It seems inconsistent.